# Laravel calling queue worker from other artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, command, queue, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I want to call my queue:work from a build script. Problem is I want to determine which queue to use based on an env variable i'm setting on the server. I'm i safe to use a command like the one I wrote.
What happens if the worker stops working. Can i restart the worker gracefully?
Anny tips or suggestions are welcome!

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;


use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class SetupQueueWorker extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'queue:setup-worker';

    const QUEUE_TO_USE_ENV_KEY = 'USE_QUEUE';

    public function handle()
    {
        //php artisan queue:work --tries=2 --queue=so_test --sleep=5
        $queueToUse = env(self::QUEUE_TO_USE_ENV_KEY);
        if(is_null($queueToUse))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Environment variable to determine which queue should be used is not set. Env key: '.self::QUEUE_TO_USE_ENV_KEY);
        }
        $exit = Artisan::call('queue:work', [
            '--tries' => 2, '--queue' => $queueToUse, '--sleep' => 5
        ]);
        throw new \RuntimeException('Queue worker stopped listing.');
    }


}
```

Comment: This looks like a wrapper around the queue worker. Problem is you now need to worry about the queue worker stopping AND this script stopping (which will kill the queue worker). Laravel suggests [using Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration) to keep the worker running

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is on running the program on heroku and can't activate supervisor myself. I did some more research and it seems like heroku has something out of the box for processing failing and restarting them. Thanks anyway.